# Delete lines which contains less than 3 words

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to Delete lines which contains less than 3 words:

I tried such regex `^.+\s.+\s.+$` but it selects all lines:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex would match all the lines which has less than 3 words ie, upto two words.

```
^ *\S+\s(?:\S+)? *$
```

OR

```
^ *\S+ *(?:\S+)? *$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bW3pG2/4)

To match all the lines which has atmost three words.

```
^ *\S+ *(\S+ *(?:\S+)?)? *$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bW3pG2/5)